# How to select the last / latest edited row in Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table T1, which contains id and name. If the name is updated from front end, it then creates a new row with updated name, hence creating two row for the same id. I want to get the last or latest updated row from the table. **Note:The table is not capturing any date or time column**. Below is the example, here I have to get the latest record with name Albert Dazy. **I am using Sql Server 2008**

```
Table T1:
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |     id              |   name           |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |      abc_0011       |      Albert      |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |      abc_0011       |      Dazy        |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |      abc_0011       |      Albert Dazy |
    |---------------------|------------------|
```

I am not capturing time for the record, can it be done without datetime logic? Like, calculating the logic of time internally?

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you the desired results.

```
;with CTE as(
select ID,name,row_number()over(partition by id order by id desc) RID
from #tmp
)
select C.ID,C.Name from CTE C JOIN (select max(RID) MRID,ID FROM CTE GROUP BY ID) T ON C.RID=T.MRID AND C.id=T.id
```